# Mysql order on calculation with variable from outside tables

Tags: mysql

Can I do a calculation like this in MySQL:

```
somefield * (someotherfield * somethirdfield - MYVALUE)
```

where MYVALUE would be filled in to the query using my client?

Comment: You need to use parameterized query. Pass `MYVALUE` as input/parameter.

Comment: cool thanks! If you make this an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parameterized query. Pass `MYVALUE` as input/parameter.

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

parameterized (named) queries has `@` prefix, thus

```
somefield * (someotherfield * somethirdfield - @myVal)
```

if you are using `ODBC` client, then you need to use `?` since ODBC client does not support named parameters.

```
somefield * (someotherfield * somethirdfield - ?)
```

Depending on the client which you are using you need to formulate the rest. You can check **parameterized queries**